# Live Data Observer - Wait for RESUMED State

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-lifecycle

This is my scenario:

1. User presses a button
2. A long slow animation is played
3. While animation is being played - user presses the home button and
   goes to homescreen
4. The animation completes in background and sets a live data value
5. When the app resumes the observer of the live data gets notified and
       does a fragment transaction.
6. The notification happens during onStart due to the following line in the source code of Live Data:

   `static boolean isActiveState(State state) {return state.isAtLeast(STARTED);}`

So the question is how can I make the observer wait until **at least resumed** state is achieved. As fragment transaction needs to take place when activity has completely resumed.

Comment: You can use `static boolean isActiveState(State state) {return state.isAtLeast(ON_RESUME);}`
Check this for more details: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Lifecycle.Event.html

Comment: so I need to override the method of Live Data or do I have to build a Lifecycle Aware component ?

Comment: That's your call. Extend `LiveData` if you require to notify your observers when they are in either `STARTED` or `RESUMED` state. For example, sending sensor data to `Activity`.
While `LifecycleObserver` are much more generic.